# Twitter Coding, but unexpected EOF while parsing, need helo

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I wanted to create a twitter bot with a simple coding but however I get this error
It should show or print out any csv with a specific tweet with the user name and the rest.
File "", line 37

user, source, tweetId,tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),])
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
    import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
import ssl
import time
####input your credentials here
consumer_key = "CNS18gUCgMqbMcuP0O88uLOfy"
consumer_secret = "ewqfl0jruElVFEy0uGkZLH118LFbGQxIfqi4V9dNzaoKhelsGY"
access_key = "749662970658033664-2CzHlLY2VmoiEX871w1rlCrs5kimPcp"
access_secret = "pU2UosrAa6n9GRK1ubjb02n5OWKgmd8LVPkrGF6PEvUSu"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('musicalbum.csv', 'a', encoding="UTF-8")
global writer

#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

def on_status(self, status):
    try:
# Save other information from the tweet
        user = status.author.screen_name
        timeTweet = status.created_at
        source = status.source
        tweetId = status.id

        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#albumreview",count=100,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2020-01-01").items():
            print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)

        writer.writerow([tweet, keywords_strings, timeTweet,
                user, source, tweetId,tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: unsure of it, that why i am asking for a helping hand

Comment: The `writer.writerow(` part should be within the final `for` loop. So indent that accordingly and try again.